# query failedERROR: prepared statement "my_query" does not exist

Tags: php, postgresql, prepared-statement, pg-query

**Hello All**

I'm trying to insert a form data into my postgreSQL DB in heroku through PHP and i tried all the solutions here but nothing solved my problem!. I can connect to the database but no operation worked well to me!. **This error lead me to craziness!.**

my code is:

```
<?php


   $db_conn = pg_connect(" host="" port=5432 dbname="" user="" password="" ");

    if(!$db_conn){
             echo "Error : Unable to connect the database\n";
          } 


  if (isset($_POST['savedata'])) {


   $fn    =  $_POST ['fullname']; 
   $em    =  $_POST ['email']; 
   $ag    =  $_POST ['age'];
   $ge    =  $_POST ['gender'] ; 
   $ci    =  $_POST ['city'] ; 
   $de    =  $_POST ['degree']; 
   $ex    =  $_POST ['experience'];
   $jo    =  $_POST ['job']; 



  if($fn != "" and $em != "" and $ag != "" and $ge != "" and $ci != "" and $de != "" and $ex != "" and $jo != "") {


  $data1="something to test";



  $result = pg_prepare($db_conn, "my_query", "INSERT INTO members (fullname, email, age, gender, city, degree, experience, job) VALUES ($fn, $em, $ag, $ge, $ci, $de, $ex, $jo)");
  $result = pg_execute($db_conn, "my_query", array($data1));

  if (!$result){
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    die("query failed".pg_last_error());
  }

  else {

  echo "<script>";
  echo "document.querySelector('.myalert').style.display = 'block';";
  echo "setTimeout(function(){
        document.querySelector('.myalert').style.display = 'none';
        window.location.replace('home');
      },5000);"; 
  echo "</script>";

 }

  }

  else {
    echo "<script>";
    echo "document.querySelector('.myalert1').style.display = 'block';";
    echo "setTimeout(function(){
        document.querySelector('.myalert1').style.display = 'none';
      },2000);"; 
    echo "</script>";
  }

 }


?>
```

Comment: You have a quoting issue in your very first line

Comment: Tell me exactly in which line the quotation issue?

Comment: From looking at the [examples](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-prepare.php), you should use single quotes when preparing your query instead of double quotes. Double quotes will expand your variables, but you instead want to leave the actual variable names in.

Comment: Look at the highlighting in the code here. The quotes in your `pg_connect` statement are throwing things off.

Comment: Ok i will try to surround them by a single ' '

Comment: I think you also need to change your variable names in your prepare query. `If any parameters are used, they are referred to in the query as $1, $2, etc.`

Comment: @aynber Don't focus on the missing " in the end of pg_connect function because i forgot to put here but it is already exist in my code, so i will edit the post now.

Comment: How i can do that @aynber?

Comment: Please do not re-type your code here by hand.  Instead, copy/paste the exact code whenever possible.

Comment: @PatrickQ Yes i did that copy/paste but only forgot " in the end of pg_connect(). I will try your solution with a single ' ' and give you the results ok.

Comment: @PatrickQ i got the same error :(

Comment: @PatrickQ Check it from here https://thegate2018.herokuapp.com/

Comment: See [aynber's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51546878/query-failederror-prepared-statement-my-query-does-not-exist#comment90061716_51546878).  Your call to `pg_prepare()` is likely failing.  You should be checking the result of that call before you execute.

Comment: @PatrickQ Can you give me the proper code to solve this or not?

Comment: Not with that kind of attitude, no.  Goodbye.

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax error in your code at the very first line.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '" port=5432 dbname="' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ')
```

There are also some other issues and oddities so it was just easier to rewrite some parts of your code.

I would also advice you to pay little more attention about the coding style, indentations and etc. It would be significantly easier to read and help you if the code were styled properly. [PSR-2 Style Guide](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) would be good place to start.

So here's the rewritten code, but **note** that I don't have PostgreSQL installed and that's why the code below isn't tested in any way. It should work, but there's also possibility that it doesn't.

See the comments in the code for further explanation.

```php
// Change these credentials according to your needs, but without any quotes
$db_conn = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=mydb user=user password=pwd");

if (!$db_conn) {
    die("Error : Unable to connect the database\n");
}

if (isset($_POST['savedata'])) {
    $member_details = array(
        $_POST['fullname'],
        $_POST['email'],
        $_POST['age'],
        $_POST['gender'],
        $_POST['city'],
        $_POST['degree'],
        $_POST['experience'],
        $_POST['job']
    );
}

// Iterates through the array and checks if there's any items of which has no proper value
foreach ($member_details as $key => $val) {
    if (empty($val)) {
        die($key . ' is empty.');
    }
}

// Query inside single quotes, also variable names must be $1, $2, $3 etc
$query = 'INSERT INTO members (fullname, email, age, gender, city, degree, experience, job) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $5, $7, $8)';

$result = pg_prepare($db_conn, "my_query", $query);
$result = pg_execute($db_conn, "my_query", $member_details);

if (!$result) {
    // error actions
} else {
    // success actions
}
```

Comment: Not working :(( and the same error i got it. By the way, i'm trying to heroku postgre sql not a local postgre sql.

Comment: Can you help me?

Comment: Now i got only query failed

Comment: I got this error now: query failedERROR: bind message supplies 1 parameters, but prepared statement "my_query" requires 8

Comment: It's most likely because $member_details doesn't have exactly 8 items in it in the statement you're trying to execute. It's size must correspond with the query parameters.